# Virtualenvwrapper - workon is throwing a weird error & behaving strangely

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have installed `virtualenvwrapper` & it was working properly few days back.

Now, when I run `workon`, it is taking more than 30 seconds to execute it. It is activating the virualenv and throwing this error and changing the working dir to virtualenv dir.

```
k3 @ k3-desktop at ~/project/test $ workon my_env

virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:19: job table full or recursion limit exceeded
(my_env) k3 @ k3-desktop at ~/.virtualenvs/pearl $
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you have a preactivate and/or postactivate scripts on your virtualenv configuration ?

Comment: @QuentinTHEURET I removed pre/postactivate scripts. Now working dir is not changing. But still it is taking ~1 min to execute `workon` & it's throwing error.

Comment: Check for other hooks because the error 'virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:19' determines the method that calls the hooks.

Comment: @QuentinTHEURET Found that `autoenv` is messing it. If i remove `autoenv` everything is working fine. But I want to keep `autoenv` also.